# How can I click an anchor tag inside a list item?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, listitem

I am trying to click the anchor tag inside the list item with raw js. How can I do it?

Code:

```
<li class="next">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-link">
        <img src="/images/arrow-right.png" alt="newer">
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Put the a tag outside. `<a...><li...><img...></li></a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('btn-link')[0].click();
```

Or you can give the `<a>` tag an id and do this:

```js
document.getElementById('myId').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but simply you can create a javascript function in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the html page, and then tell the `<a>` anchor which function to call using the `onclick` attribute

```html
<ul>
  <li class="next">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-link" onclick="doClick(this)">
          <img src="/images/arrow-right.png" alt="newer">
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  function doClick(elem) {
    console.log('clicked!', elem);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I am trying to do this without changing the source code. Thanks though!